# How to insert a simple message into the JUnit output?

Tags: java, junit, errorcollector

Is there a way to add a message to the JUnit output? Just now I can to add an exception with that message to the ErrorCollector, but thus I will have the message *and the stack* and I don't need the last. And I would like to add the message *before* errors.

The idea was: while checking the XML, to collect all discrepancies and at the end, if there were some errors, to output the XML itself and the errors after it.

**edit:**
Please, notice, I want to add to the existing output, not to output only my messages.

Comment: Normally I would just add log statements using the logging framework of my choice. Would this suffice for you?

Comment: @DuncanJones It works OK if you have a single project. But if you work with tens and hundreds of projects, and all of them could write something to JUnit, something to the log, the result is unreadable. So the solution is bad, because it is not **scalable**. (I used that before and it is very inconvenient)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for `ErrorCollector` to have slightly different behavior.  The best solution would be to just roll your own version.

Here's the source of `ErrorCollector`: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.java

Here's a quick version if you only care about strings and don't need the stack traces.  If you want to collect the stack traces, too, but just display all the strings first, I'll leave that code up to you.

```
public class ErrorMessageCollector extends Verifier {
    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void verify() throws Throwable {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String e : errors) {
            sb.append(e).append('\n');
        }
        assertTrue(sb.toString(), errors.isEmpty());
    }

    /**
     * Adds an error message to the table. Execution continues, but the test 
     * will fail at the end.
     */
    public void addErrorMessage(String error) {
        errors.add(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you are proposing to break the existing mechanism of error message collecting and replace it with String collecting. No, thanks. I want to collect Strings and Exception messages. What you are "leaving to me", is just my question. Thank you for the reference... But I have reread this page already about 5 times from the morning. The answer is not there.

Comment: The above sounds exactly like the answer to your question. Seems like you need to clarify your question as we both thought this would solve what you asked for.

Comment: The question sounds: How to insert a message in output, not how to output only messages instead of the usual content. You have advised me a good idea and I did extend the verifier myself - for checking if there are errors in the Collector. But the question remains unanswered, sorry.

Comment: @Gangnus If you've got a solution that works, you should post it and mark it as the solution.

Comment: I haven't the solution to the question, I am adding a new exception with my message, but due to your idea I can check if I have to add it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own Error Collector. Is should be easy to wrap existing assert methods, catch the exception and keep track of if you got any failures. If you wrote this as a rule it could be assessed after each test with you having to do it manually.

Comment: I already use my own VariantErrorCollector. But I hadn't found in  source code of ErrorCollector any place where a string is written to the JUnit output.

Comment: @Gangnus "*I already use my own VariantErrorCollector.*" > This sort of information is rather useful in your question!

Comment: No, because a class derived from ErrorCollector won't allow to check number of errors and add a String instead of the message.